# Laravel 5.5 - API ID not found 404 instead of JSON

Tags: laravel

I am using findOrFail on a Laravel 5.5 API route like this...

```
public function getCategory(Request $request, $id) {

    /* Get Category From ID */
    try {
        $category = Category::with('users')->findOrFail($id);
    }

    /* catch(Exception $e) catch any exception */
    catch(ModelNotFoundException $e) {

        /* Return Success Response */
        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => true,
            'status_code' => 400,
            'response' => 'category_id_not_found',
        ));

    }
}
```

If I put in an ID that does not exists then I get a 404 error instead of the JSON response.

Where am I going wrong?

### Update

Turns out I wasn't including

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
```

in the controller, thanks to Sohel0415 for making me look in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `NotFoundHttpException`:

```
public function getCategory(Request $request, $id) {

/* Get Category From ID */
 try {
     $category = Category::with('users')->findOrFail($id);
 }

 /* catch(Exception $e) catch any exception */
 catch(NotFoundHttpException $e) {

     /* Return Success Response */
     return Response::json(array(
        'error' => true,
        'status_code' => 400,
        'response' => 'category_id_not_found',
    ));

 }
}
```

Or you can do the following:

```
public function getCategory(Request $request, $id) {

    $category = Category::with('users')->find($id);
    if($category!=null){
        return Response::json(array(
        'status_code' => 200,
        'category' => $category,
       )); 
    }

    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => true,
        'status_code' => 400,
        'response' => 'category_id_not_found',
    ));

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`findOrFail` method returns an object or throws an error if it's not found, as in [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models), you might want to use `find` method and check for model existence with `if($category)`.